# Is there an easy way to look at key-value pairs in a Dictionary using sos?

Tags: .net, dictionary, windbg, sos

I'm using SOS.dll via WinDBG looking at a crash dump.  Given the address of a Dictionary object, is there an easy way to dump it's contents like..

```
Key1 -> Value1
Key2 -> Value2
...
KeyN -> ValueN
```

I see there is no !DumpDictionary command :(

Answer (score 4):

No, but PSSCOR2/4 offers some collection support.  Look at !dc, in particular.  SOSEX supports this: !mdt  -e:2.  This command says to dump the object specified by  and expand it 2 levels.

Comment: I tried it on a generic dictionary but it complained: 0:012> !do 014ba5d0
Name:        System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib]]

0:012> !dc 014ba5d0
Going to dump the Collection passed.
0x014ba5d0 is not a supported Collection object
.chain shows: psscor4: image 4.0.0.4, API 1.0.0, built Tue Feb 01 15:39:38 2011

Comment: OK, I thought !dc supported Dictionary.  Try !sosex.mdt -e:2 or -e:3.

Comment: That worked! And looks like one of my devs has a bug since key is null: 0:012> !mdt 014ba5d0 -e:3
014ba5d0 (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib]])
Count = 1
[0] (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2+Entry[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Int32, mscorlib]]) VALTYPE (MT=73a90790, ADDR=014be4f0)
    key:NULL (System.__Canon)
    value:0x0 (System.Int32)

Comment: Beware to take a look at the dictionary count property. Since the KeyValuePair Collection allocation is dynamic, the framework allocates more chunks (to perform fewer allocations). In my case dictionary.count = 60d and my entries collection has 89 elements. Every element from 61th to the 89th being null (key and value).